# Add WCF Client tag prefix

Tags: wcf

I am trying to make my .NET WCF client talk to JAVA based Web Service via SOAP11.

The problem I ran into was that the web service expects `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header></s:Header><s:Body><web:SayHello xmlns:web="http://webservice.com/"...`

while .NET is providing the following:

`<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header></s:Header><s:Body><SayHello xmlns="http://webservice.com/"...`.

Basically the SayHello element, i.e. method is **not** prefixed with the namespace pointer ***web***, neither is the **xmlns** declaration.

My thoughts take me to intercepting the message and reassembling the XML where I would manually append the prefix. I don't like this workaround though.

If anyone knows of a more elegant solution I would appreciate it highly.

Thanks in advance.

N.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, but still I had to edit the intercepted message.

The answer is here
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/6500146/354484 answered by a link provided by carlosfigueira.

If anyone still knows the solution, e.g. attribute of config based, then please come back.

Cheers,

N.